# How do I get different values for finished build based on who triggered it in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a code in Jenkins in groovy which sends notifications to Slack with information who started a build:

```
def startedBy = "${env.BUILD_USER_ID}"
def message =  "\nJob started by: ${startedBy}"
return message
```

I am using `build-vars-plugin`

There are three variants:

- if build is started via UI  or triggered by another, starting pipeline = then I see `Job started by: john.doe`
- if build is started via curl = then I see `Job started by: remoteHost`
- fi build is started via cron = then I see `Job started by: timer`

How can I rewrite that script so I can see:

- `Job started by: john.doe@example.com` whenever value consist of two fields `name.surname` + I add same mail for all people in company
- `Job started by: remoteHost` when started remotely by curl
- `Job started by: timer` when started by cron

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you only need to change the variant when user manually triggers the build, so, instead of `Job started by: john.doe` you want to have `Job started by: john.doe@example.com`, is it correct?

Comment: No. I want to add `@example.com` only when user triggered a job, in other cases there can be `remoteHost` or `timer` as there is no user involved. Env $BUILD_USER_ID gives user, timer or remoteHost accordingly to who triggered it.

Comment: Not sure I understand what is the difference between what you say and my previous comment :) Anyway, I've posted an answer to your question how I understood it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways how to solve it:

1. As you say, we may rely on the fact that your users always have a format `{forename}.{surname}`. Then we should try to split the `BUILD_USER_ID` value by `.` and check if there are two pieces.
2. We may also rely that those two user IDs `remoteHost` and `timer` are constant and exclude them.

I've implemented both versions. Take a look at the situation when username is `tommy`. The functions return different results.

```
[
    'john.doe',
    'max.mustermann',
    'tommy',
    'timer',
    'remote'
].each {
    println "env.BUILD_USER_ID: ${it}; createMessage1: '${createMessage1(it)}'; createMessage2: '${createMessage2(it)}'"
}

String createMessage1(String userId) {
    def startedBy
    if (userId?.split("\\.")?.size() == 2) {
        startedBy = "${userId}@example.com"
    } else {
        startedBy = userId
    }
    "Job started by: ${startedBy}"
}

String createMessage2(String userId) {
    def startedBy
    if (!(userId in ['timer', 'remoteHost'])) {
        startedBy = "${userId}@example.com"
    } else {
        startedBy = userId
    }
    "Job started by: ${startedBy}"
}
```

I hope it will help you to move forward.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I will try to implement that.